# OpenVPN clients still getting assigned same ip with duplicate-cn in server config

Tags: linux, openvpn

Clients are still getting assigned same ip as each other even with duplicate-cn in server the config. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've restarted all the machines involved after changing the config. Here is my server.conf.

```
port 1194
proto tcp6
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
server-ipv6 fd42:42:42:42::/112
tun-ipv6
push tun-ipv6
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "redirect-gateway ipv6"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_PxV2VymBrucFUPiE.crt
key server_PxV2VymBrucFUPiE.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
duplicate-cn
client-to-client
verb 3
```

Comment: You didn't check the logs. Look at the log entries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton /var/log/openvpn/status.log is empty.  is there somewhere else to look?

Comment: You didn't configure a log location, so they will be sent to syslog.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton.  There's nothing particularly interesting there.  It just says this over and over.  ```Sep 27 01:05:48 localhost systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to server.
Sep 27 01:05:53 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Sep 27 01:05:53 localhost systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
Sep 27 01:05:53 localhost ovpn-server[19070]: OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 19 2021
```

Comment: It does think it's tomorrow for some reason.  not sure if that matters.

Comment: You need to go back to the time that the actual problem was happening.

Comment: @MichaelHampton When I try to log in to two clients at the same time they both keep trying to reconnect after an initial successful connection.  Otherwise I have not logged in nearly as many times as it's logges, so I think I'm looking at the right time.

Comment: same results with ver set to 11

Comment: @MichaelHampton I moved the config file and restarted via systemd and everything is working the same.. maybe I'm not using the config that I think I am, but I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: could it have something to do with ipp.txt?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. You chose to have each user's IP address persist between logins, but then you made everyone the same user.

Comment: @MichaelHampton commenting it out does not fix the problem

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did manage to get some more out of syslog.  https://dpaste.org/OhYU

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not sure what the root problem is, but I burned everything to the ground and started over and now it works.  thanks for your help